# XCTest'ing a tuple

Tags: xcode, swift, tuples, xctest

I am trying to build a unit test like so:

```
// region is a (Double, Double) tuple
XCTAssertEqual(region, (0.0, 200.0))
```

But Xcode is giving me an error: `Cannot invoke 'XCTAssertEqual' with an argument list of type ((Double, Double), (Double, Double))`

Is there a different way to test tuples without extracting their members and testing individually?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`XCTAssertEqual` requires that the two parameters passed to it are `Equatable`, which you can see from the method signature. Note that `expression1` returns `T?`, and `T` must be `Equatable`:

```
func XCTAssertEqual<T : Equatable>(_ expression1: @autoclosure () throws -> T?, _ expression2: @autoclosure () throws -> T?, _ message: @autoclosure () -> String = default, file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line)
```

But [Swift tuples aren't `Equatable`](http://mjtsai.com/blog/2016/05/24/swift-tuples-arent-equatable/), so you can't use them with `XCTAssertEqual`.

Tuples *do* have an `==` method — they just don't conform to the protocol — so you could do something like this:

```
let eql = region == (0.0, 200.0)
XCTAssertTrue(eql)
```

Or even:

```
XCTAssertTrue(region == (0.0, 200.0))
```

Comment: I tried `let eql = region == (0.0, 200.0)` but it's still giving me the error that `==` can't be applied to tuples. I'm running Swift 2.1.1 if that matters.

Comment: I'm not sure when they added it, but it's relatively new. You will need to use a later version of Swift or test the elements individually. I think you could also write your own custom equality operator.

Comment: Tuple comparison operators were added in Swift 2.2. Since you're on 2.1, you can copy and modify the == implementation here: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0015-tuple-comparison-operators.md

Answer (score 8):

*Edit: I've expanded on this answer in a blog post, [How to Make Specialized Test Assertions in Swift](https://qualitycoding.org/swift-test-assertions/)*

A disadvantage of using

```
XCTAssertTrue(region == (0.0, 200.0))
```

is the inadequate reporting it gives upon failure:

> XCTAssertTrue failed -

Now you have to track down what the actual values are, to understand what went wrong.

But you can add diagnostic information to the assertion like this:

```
XCTAssertTrue(region == (0.0, 200.0), "was \(region)")
```

For example:

> XCTAssertTrue failed - was (1.0, 2.0)

If you plan to have several tests that compare this tuple, I wouldn't want to have to repeat this everywhere. Instead, create a custom assertion:

```
private func assertRegionsEqual(actual: (_: Double, _: Double), expected: (_: Double, _: Double), file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
    if actual != expected {
        XCTFail("Expected \(expected) but was \(actual)", file: file, line: line)
    }
}
```

Now the test assertion is

```
assertRegionsEqual(actual: region, expected: (0.0, 200.0))
```

Upon failure, this yields a message like

> failed - Expected (0.0, 200.0) but was (1.0, 2.0)

Comment: This is a great idea, although it doesn't address my specific issue. It wound up being that equality tests for tuples were introduced on Swift 2.2, and I'm running 2.1.1. But I'll be using this in conjunction with writing my own equality test.