# Compare array of tuples in swift

Tags: swift, tuples

I've declared the following for my `tuple` type:

```swift
public typealias Http2HeaderTableEntry = (field: String, value: String?)

func ==(lhs: [Http2HeaderTableEntry], rhs: [Http2HeaderTableEntry]) -> Bool {
    guard lhs.count == rhs.count else { return false }

    for (idx, element) in lhs.enumerated() {
        guard element.field == rhs[idx].field && element.value == rhs[idx].value else {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

But now when I try and use it in an assertion, like `XCTAssertEqual(var1, var2)` I'm getting a compiler error:

> Cannot invoke 'XCTAssertEqual' with an argument list of type '([Http2HeaderTableEntry], [Http2HeaderTableEntry])'

What do I need to do in order to be able to compare two arrays of tuples in Swift 4?

Comment: The values passed to `XCTAssertEqual` need to conform to `Equatable`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XCTest'ing a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38175690/xctesting-a-tuple)

Answer (score 0):

Since tuples can't have conformances yet, there's not really a way to implement this in any general way at this point.

[Reference here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4085)